# pass value to bootstrap modal form with django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

When I use bootstrap modal for my form its only show first value.

here my `template.html`

```
{% for company in companys %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ company.desc }}</td>
    <td align="center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning margin-bottom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default2">
            delete
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default2">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <form method="post" action="{% url 'system:company_delete' pk=company.pk %}">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="modal-content">    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_name" value="{{ company.pk }}">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete">
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

its loop all the data, when click `delete` confirm form will popup. but its return same value.

but if without modal-bootstrap its work fine.

example: `template.html`

```
{% for company in companys %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ company.desc }}</td>
    <td align="center">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'system:company_delete' pk=company.pk %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_name" value="{{ company.pk }}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

it's work fine.

what I should do to make it work?...

***update***

`views.py`

```
# Company Crud
class CompanyListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'companys'
    model = models.Company

class CompanyCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'desc')
    model = models.Company

class CompanyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ('name', 'desc')
    model = models.Company

class CompanyDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = models.Company
    success_url = reverse_lazy("system:company_list")
```

Comment: As you iterate over the loop, you're creating a modal for each `company`, but they all have the same `id`. When you call your modals, only one of them gets called (not sure how bs modal works, but probably it's the first one). So you should restructure your template to put the modal parent div outside of your loop.

Comment: Does your `company.name`and `company.desc` render perfectly?

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't think that far. Do i need loop modal or can use one?... Put the modal outside loop?.. but how to pass the id?...

Comment: @Dhaval Savalia yes off course.

Comment: its bad idea if loop the modals, if have 1000 more data it will lot of html code.

Comment: what's triggered the modal? what button?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Your ajax modal will always return the same value inside modal because:
 - Modal has this `data-target="#modal-default2"` as the target, however, your loop contains the modal body, with the id `id="modal-default2"`, which will render modal as much as your loop goes.

So what you can do is to define a unique ID for each modal with the ID of each company `modal-default{{company.id}}`:

```
{% for company in companys %}
    ''' rest of codes '''
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning margin-bottom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default{{company.id}}">
        delete
    </button>
    ''' rest of codes '''

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default{{company.id}}">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        </div>
    </div>
    ''' rest of codes '''
{% endfor %}
```

> But this method is not effective if you have a lot of data, it will render lots of html codes.

### Another option

With AJAX  and one modal.

**Your html would be:**

```
{% for company in companys %}
    <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ company.desc }}</td>

    <button data-id="{{company.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-warning margin-bottom delete-company" >
        delete
    </button> <!-- be aware of class 'delete-company' -->
{% endfor %}
{% csrf_token %}


<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        {% if company %} <!-- this company instance will come from AJAX -->
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'system:company_delete' pk=company.pk %}">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="modal-content">    
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_name" value="{{ company.pk }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete">
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-company',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url:'',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            'id':id,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#modal-default .modal-dialog').html($('#modal-default .modal-dialog',data));
            $('#modal-default').modal('show');
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('error')
        },
    });
});
```

And your `views` would be:

> change your url from `CompanyListView.as_view()` to `companyListView`

```
def companyListView(request):
    context = {}
    companys = models.Company.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        ID = request.POST.get('id')
        company = companys.get(id=ID) # So we send the company instance
        context['company'] = company
    context['companys'] = companys
    return render(request,'template.html',context)
```

Comment: which option that you choose? first or second?

Comment: got an error `UnboundLocalError at /system/company/
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment`

Comment: did you add this line `context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**context)`?

Comment: Sorry, instead of `context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**context` add `context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`

Comment: oh okay, but another problem `Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'object_list'` :'D

Comment: `object_list` means the name of your queryset,, in your case, it's 'companys'

Comment: my mistake: `context['companys']` not `kwargs['companys']`. let's continue to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170445/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-dicky-raambo).