# Pass for loop button value to modal bootstrap django

Tags: html, django

I've been looking around for this problem and while there are many threads, most use javascrip, ajax, or other stuff that I don't know...

I have a list called `movies` that contain lists of movies and all their information.

I'm using this to display all movies in a table.

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
        <td>
        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#myModal">
            {{movie.0}}     <!--   The movie name-->
        </a>
        </td>
     <td>{{movie.3}}</td>.     <!--   The movie rating-->
     <td><a href="">Add</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And a trimmed version of my modal looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalTitle"
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{movies.0}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly my `views.py` looks like this.

```
def search_movie(request):
    info_for_all_movies = []
    recommender = MovieRecommender()
    form = MovieForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'search_movie' in request.POST:
            movie = request.POST.get('name')
            movies = recommender.recommend_movie(movie) # returns a list containing the name, director, rating, description, etc...
            for movie in movies:
                movie_info = recommender.get_movie_info(movie)
                info_for_all_movies.append(movie_info)

    context = {'movies': info_for_all_movies, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'movie/dashboard.html', context)
```

Obviously, no matter which movie I click i will only get the description of the first movie because of `{{movies.0}}`. Im wondering how can I pass the correct index to the modal so I can do maybe something like `{{movies.pk}}` where `pk` would be the index corresponding to the movie I pressed?

Comment: Show us your `views.py` too or a list you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Feel kinda dumb as it was pretty simple even though maybe not the most efficient solution. I named my button `id="myModal{{movie}}"` and my modal `data-target="#myModal{{movie}}">`.

Found the answer at: [pass value to bootstrap modal form with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196148/pass-value-to-bootstrap-modal-form-with-django)

There is a better solution with AJAX but I dont know where to put that code.